# That "that" - when use it?

Tags: word-usage, style

I never understood the difference between

- I prove 1+1=2
- I prove that 1+1=2

Likewise umpty more similar sentence pairs.
When is "that" mandatory, when is it only a matter of style, and which style is preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a **that-clause**.  You can find more information from the Cambridge Dictionary [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses).  This is the **verb + that-clause** version using a reporting verb "prove".  The same dictionary has an article about reporting verbs and "that" [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause).

Reading further in the second article, they provide examples of when "that" is left out:

> We often leave out *that* after these verbs, especially in informal speaking. This is sometimes called **zero-that**. This is especially common after *guess, think, hope* and *reckon*.

Based on this and [other information I found](https://web.ku.edu/%7Eedit/that.html#:%7E:text=When%20to%20use%20%22that%22&text=After%20a%20verb%20of%20attribution,that.%22%20Better%20to%20omit.), I would suggest that you remove "that" from your sentences only when the intended meaning of the sentence can still be clearly discerned.

As for which style is preferable, I can't say definitively.  I did find [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jhsl-2015-0003/html) which talks about the usage of both styles through the ages.